# Como importar um arquivo css dentro do JSX por tag link ou script (React)

Tags: javascript, html, css, react

Olá, estou aprendendo React, vi alguns conceitos básicos em um micro-curso no youtube, e pra treinar eu gostaria de transformar um site que já tenho em html e bootstrap para react.

Um dos problemas que encontrei é que não consegui importar "direto" a parte onde está meus scripts javascript/css.

O que não é reconhecido, e portanto ele não aplica a estilização/javascript:

`App.jsx`

```
import React from "react";
function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <link href="./static/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
            <link href="./static/lib/Ionicons/css/ionicons.css" />
            <link href="./static/lib/perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.min.css" />
            <restante do HTML>
        </>
);

export default App
```

O que funciona:

```
import React from 'react'
import './static/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'
import './static/lib/Ionicons/css/ionicons.css'
import './static/lib/perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.min.css'

function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <HTML>
        </>
);

export default App
```

Tem como realizar a importação por dentro do JSX, como se fosse um HTML normal? Como posso fazer isso? Tentei colocar dentro da pasta "public", mas também não deu certo.

Comment: Tem algum motivo pra você querer fazer isso em detrimento das importações diretamente no JS?

Comment: eu tenho alguns scripts que são importados no final do arquivo, como por exemplo popper, bootstrap, jquery, etc. Eu tentei incluir esses arquivos dentro do meu arquivo HTML (index.html, que fica dentro da pasta public, mas mesmo assim os javascripts não funcionam - acertei o path). Pra criar o meu app react eu usei o comando de "create-react-app".

Comment: Deves manter isso "à maneira antiga". Sem importar para o React.

Comment: o que você quer dizer com isso? deve ser mantido no html?

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que vc terá que refatorar o código usando os imports da forma que é feito no React, ou então vc pode colocar esse código HTML dentro do Index que fica na pasta public. Quanto ao JavaScript eu não tenho certeza mas o CSS é carregado normalmente depois da aplicação ter sido compilada.